# MongoDB $and returing unexpected result?

Tags: mongodb

I've just stumbled upon an unexpected behavior of MongoDB:

```
db.photosLambda.find({'analysis': {$exists: true}, 'analysis_lambda': {$exists: true}}).count()
db.photosLambda.find({$and: [{'analysis': {$exists: true}}, {'analysis_lambda': {$exists: true}}]}).count()
```

I do not understand why the second query should return an empty result, whereas the first one returns what I expect, that are, all the elements in the `photosLambda` collection that have both `'analysis'` and `'analysis_lambda'` set to something.

Any clue on this?

**Update:** Thanks the comments below, I realized that I was running an "outdated" version of mongo: the `$and` operator was introduced in v2.0 (I was using v1.6).

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  `$and` was introduced in v2.0.

Comment: Also, what indexes do you have? Are they sparse indexes?

Comment: maybe you can post the document you are expecting back - both syntaxes work for me.

Comment: Did you end up solving your problem, or are you going to provide some further information for someone to try to answer? :)

Comment: Woops, I didn't know that `$and` was introduced in v2.0. I'm going to close the question.